# Ubuntu 17.10 Gnome Desktop Right Click Context Menu

Tags: gnome, mouse, 17.10

Since doing a clean install of Ubuntu 17.10 with the GNOME desktop, I've noticed that there is no right mouse click context menu functionality in any application so far tested.

I find this to be a glaring oversight by Ubuntu.  Ubuntu should definitely have fixed this issue before the product was released into the wild.

Can someone advise how I go about enabling the Right Mouse Click Context Menus in 17.10 GNOME so that I get right click functionality in all apps.

Or - if the absence of right mouse click context menus is a "feature" of GNOME Shell, then please advise and I'll change to another distro!

Comment: Could you be more specific? What app did you try? Are you sure your right mouse button is working? There's a simple tester in Settings > Devices > Mouse & Touchpad > Test Your Settings. The right-click should show up as "secondary button".

Comment: Changing to another distro will not help if you do not like gnome-shell, you have to change to another DE such as KDE or mate or xfce or ....

Comment: Just to be clear, there's no point complaining to us. We're Ubuntu users like you, not devs.

Comment: This is a valid question, I had the same problem on my touchbad. The solution is simple as described here: https://tribaal.io/fixing-right-click-with-gnome3-in-1710.html Once I set gnome-tweak-tool: Keyboard & Mouse/Touchpad/Click Method: to Areas + restarted (not mentioned in the post) right click was back!